# propiedad no es miembro de la clase login

Tags: ajax, vb.net

Tengo un webmethod en vb.net y uso una lista de objetos para almacenar valores de la consulta SQL que hago, pero al compilar me genera un error que dice que valor.usuario no es miembro de Login, Login es una clase donde declaro propiedades

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function Login(ByVal userid As String, ByVal password As String) As List(Of Login)

    Dim datosLogin As New List(Of Login)
    Dim cn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cadenaConexion").ConnectionString
    Dim conexion As New SqlConnection(cn)

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Usuario='" & userid & "' AND Contrasena='" & password & "'")
    cmd.Connection = conexion
    conexion.Open()

    Dim loginok As String
    loginok = "Page.html"

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If dr.HasRows Then
        While dr.Read()
            Dim valor As New Login
            valor.usuario = Convert.ToString(dr.GetString(1))
            valor.password = Convert.ToString(dr.GetString(2))
            valor.sofware = Convert.ToString(dr.GetString(5))
            valor.redireccionar = loginok
            datosLogin.Add(valor)
        End While
    End If
    Return datosLogin
End Function
```

Clase Login

```
Public Class Login
    Public Property usuario As String
    Public Property password As String
    Public Property software As String
    Public Property redireccionar As String
End Class
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Un poco raro, incluso la clase que instancias es publica,  tienes más mensajes de error que podrías agregar a tu pregunta?

Comment: no, de hecho cuando compilo no me genera ningún error pero me aparece la ventana modal de que hay un error de compilación uso visual studio 2012

Comment: Tal vez una solución sea realizar un "Rebuild solution".

Comment: @Drago25 el error no será que tienes mal escrito software en la asignación ?    valor.sofware = Convert.ToString(dr.GetString(5)), reemplaza por:  valor.software = Convert.ToString(dr.GetString(5))

Comment: Si, por eso envía el mensaje: propiedad no es miembro de la clase "login", aunque no especifica cual propiedad :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error aparentemente está porque en tú proyecto tienes creada un archivo llamado Login.aspx, por lo que en el codeBehind, te crea una clase Login también, entonces en el webMethod que creas e inicializas la clase Login te esta tomando esa clase, no la que creaste tú.
Te recomiendo cambies el nombre de la clase Login por otro e intentes.

```
Public Class UsuarioLogin
    Public Property usuario As String
    Public Property password As String
    Public Property software As String
    Public Property redireccionar As String
End Class
```

y así tu WebMethod:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function Login(ByVal userid As String, ByVal password As  String) As List(Of Login)

Dim datosLogin As New List(Of UsuarioLogin)
Dim cn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cadenaConexion").ConnectionString
Dim conexion As New SqlConnection(cn)

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Usuario='" & userid & "' AND Contrasena='" & password & "'")
cmd.Connection = conexion
conexion.Open()

Dim loginok As String
loginok = "Page.html"

Dim dr As SqlDataReader
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

If dr.HasRows Then
    While dr.Read()
        Dim valor As New UsuarioLogin
        valor.usuario = Convert.ToString(dr.GetString(1))
        valor.password = Convert.ToString(dr.GetString(2))
        valor.software = Convert.ToString(dr.GetString(5))
        valor.redireccionar = loginok
        datosLogin.Add(valor)
    End While
End If
Return datosLogin
End Function
```

Comment: si así es amigo, le cambie como comentaste y ya funcionó gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @Drago25 no hay de qué amigo, Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

En realidad el problema es que no puede encontrar la propiedad "software", ya que esta mal escrita, falta un carácter "t":

```
valor.sofware = Convert.ToString(dr.GetString(5))
```

Revisa la definición en la clase:

```
Public Class Login
    Public Property usuario As String
    Public Property password As String
    Public Property software As String
    Public Property redireccionar As String
End Class
```

En la consola también muestra otro detalle:

```
´softland´  is not a member
```

Debería ser `´software´`, revisa código de `Index.aspx` y asegurarte de escribir las propiedades correctamente.

Comment: ya le cambie pero de igual forma sigue el mismo error, de hecho no me genera error al compilar pero muestra la ventana de error de compilacion como si realmente hubiera un error

Comment: @Drago25 no puedes adjuntar una captura de pantalla de lo que mencionas?

Comment: la publique en donde esta el codigo

Comment: es lo mismo, de hecho esta leyendo "softland", debe ser "software", revisa el código de tu Index.aspx :)